# Database entry not done

Tags: database, c#-4.0

```
try
{
    // Data Source=FAHAD-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog="Student management";Integrated Security=True
    // server=FAHAD-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;database=Student management;

    String str = "Data Source=FAHAD-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Student management;Integrated Security=True;";
    String query = "Insert into Users (Username, Password) values('usern' , 'userpassword');";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);



    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    MessageBox.Show("connect with sql server");

    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Inserted sucessfully");
    usern = " ";
    userpassword = " ";
}
catch (Exception err) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
}
```

here is the code my connection is successfull and the query insterted msg is also show but cant get the entry in my db.

Comment: `cmd` needs to be `.execute`'d

Answer (score 1):

Try code below

```
try
{
    // Data Source=FAHAD-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog="Student management";Integrated Security=True
    // server=FAHAD-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;database=Student management;

    String str = "Data Source=FAHAD-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Student management;Integrated Security=True;";
    String query = "Insert into Users (Username, Password) values('usern' , 'userpassword');";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);



    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("connect with sql server");

    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Inserted sucessfully");
    usern = " ";
    userpassword = " ";
}
catch (Exception err) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
}
```

Comment: Query is inserted but  anouther problem becomes String query = "Insert into Users (Username, Password) values('usern' , 'userpassword');"; there usern and userpasswrod are those variables which is to pe inserted through text box.string usern = uname.Text;
                string userpassword = upass.Text;

Comment: in data base the usern and userpassword is inserted in every Entry

Comment: Concat username and password to sql query

Comment: How Can i Add A picture into a picture box from the user in to desktop application